# View for Last Approved Revision

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-server, view, versioning

Is there a way to create a view that displays (and links to) the last approved revision of a document or list item, even if you have permission to see the new draft version? My library has major/minor versioning enabled as well as workflow-based approvals.

I'm putting a slew of documents into draft, and expect the updates to take a few months. It would be neat if I could create a view to show the last approved revisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can get this OOTB. You have to play and do some coding for this.

Below blog talking, how to display all version but you can change/ code  to get your results.

[How to display all versions in a SharePoint list view page](http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-display-all-versions-in.html)

[How to display all versions in a SharePoint list view page – part 2](http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-display-all-versions-in.html)

Comment: that's what I thought. I needed OOTB solution :(